# How to copy data from list to list

Tags: model-view-controller, c#-3.0

I have a list in my model.I have to fill that list from data that I fetch from database.how I do it.

```
public  class attachment_model
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Patient_Id { get; set;}           
        public List <attachment_model> _attachment_model { get; set; }
    }
```

it is my class that I have list.now in controller I have to fill this list.i have to show that data on the view.

Comment: What is your mechanism to fetch data from database?

Comment: var atmentdata = db.Getattachmentname().Where(x => x.Patient_Id == key && !x.Parent_Id.HasValue).ToList();  it is the query for fetching data from database.

Comment: Then what is the problem? Just load this data into your list directly like this `_attachment_model = db.Getattachmentname().Where(x => x.Patient_Id == key && !x.Parent_Id.HasValue).ToList(); `